# I want to add ajax loading gif to my website but my code is not working

Tags: php, html, ajax, gif, loader

I am working on an uploader for my website http://notes-store.com/

I want to show a loading `.gif` image while loading the select box with my sub category options using AJAX.

My current code:

```
function category_change(kuchbhi) {
    var catID = $(kuchbhi).val();   
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "subCategory.php?category="+catID,
        beforeSend: function () {
             $("#loder").html('<img src="images/loader.gif" /> Now loding...');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#select3').html(data);
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not add it when function starts and remove it when success is called:

```
function category_change(kuchbhi) {
    $("#loder").html('<img src="images/loader.gif" /> Now loding...');
    var catID = $(kuchbhi).val();   
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "subCategory.php?category="+catID,
        success: function(data){
            $('#select3').html(data);
            $("#loder").html('');
        }
    });
}
```

Note: your selector is `#loder` and not `#loader`